# Mod Rewrite automatically update URL

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a website where I have a .htaccess file with mod rewrite, so my URL's are a bit nicer to look at and more SEO friendly.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?error=404

RewriteRule ^(admin)($|/) - [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\.php$ index.php?country=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_A-Яа-я-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\.php$ index.php?country=$1&id=$3
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/(.*)/(.*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\.php$ index.php?country=$1&subid=$5&id=$4
RewriteRule ^.+?---(.+)$ images/$1 [L,NE]
Rewriterule ^sitemap.xml$ sitemap.php [L]
```

As you can see in the above rules, there are "wildcards" meaning that in between some of the forward slashes, anything goes. The way I use it, is for language selection and naming the title to the page, ending of with the id variables to control which row in the table in the database to show. example:

http://www.domain.com/en/heaters/hot-heater/26/60.php

The above URL contains the domain / the langugage / wildcard / wildcard / id variable / id variable

Now the problem is, when the links on the page gets updated by title (let's say that the hot-heater changes name to hot-red-heater) the URL indexed by Google is not the same, and both URL's still work.

I would like to know how mod rewrite can be used to automatically update the wildcards to the correct title. Just like here on Stackoverflow, the URL has the title of this question in the URL - if I alter this in the URL, the URL automatically changes this back to the original title. How is this done?

Thanks alot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to have same behavior like Stackoverflow URLs then you need to have some server side support (e.g. PHP) as well. Consider following code snippet:

**.htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L,QSA]
```

**index.php:**

```
<?php
   $id    = $_GET['id'];
   $title = $_GET['title'];

   $dbTitle = // get title by doing a database query using $id
   // ...

   if ($title != $dbTitle) {
      // redirect with 301 to correct /<id>/<title> page
      header ('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
      header('Location: /' . $id . '/' . $dbTitle);
      exit;
   }
   // rest of your script
?>
```

This will support a URL like SO i.e. `/id/some-title`

Comment: Thanks @anabhava - that actually makes a lot of sense, and I can see how I can implement this and use it as a standard when I code. Thanks again!